# How does this refactored code make my code better?

Tags: c#

According to my lecture notes, there are benefits to refactoring the code from original code to refactor code.

Reasons for refactoring:

> Replace Temp with Query
>
> - You are using many temporary variables to
>     hold the result of an expression
> - This can result in long methods, since the
>     (temp) values are available only in local
>     scope
> - Queries, in the form of method invocation,
>     means that the value is available from any
>     method in the class.
>
> Look for a temporary variable that is assigned to once
>
> - Declare the temp as final
> - Compile
> - Extract the right-hand side of the assignment into a method
> - Compile and test

Original code

```
double basePrice = _quantity * _itemPrice;

if (basePrice > 1000)
return basePrice * 0.95;
else
return basePrice * 0.98;
```

Refactored code

```
if (basePrice() > 1000)
return basePrice() * 0.95;
else
return basePrice() * 0.98;
...
double basePrice() {
return _quantity * _itemPrice;
}
```

What are the benefits from this refactor?  Please enlightened me as I can't see what the benefits to refactoring the code are in this case.

Comment: Honestly, neither can I. Are you sure this is your lecture's notes? Refactoring basePrice into a method and calling that twice only makes things worse IMO, in case it's a multithreaded environment and a value has changed in between the calls.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is not yes to all the [on-topic questions](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Especially "Did I write that code?" and "Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?"  I think [programmers.se] is a better place for this question.

Comment: Actually we're having a small discussion in [chat] concerning that.. you are welcome to join

Comment: @all I have added the reasons as to why my lecture notes suggested the refactor

Comment: The first change I'd apply is not using `double` for money.

Comment: @CodesInChaos may your word reach god in heaven above, so that he punishes use of `double` and `float` for the job of `decimal`

Comment: @CodesInChaos why wouldnt you use double for money ??

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg its psedou-code from my lecture slies

Comment: Because it's a binary floating point type, and thus can't represent values like `0.1` or `0.98` exactly. This propagates to wrong rounding. In most languages `double` can also give different results depending on the machine or global rounding modes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have misunderstood one thing that your lecturer said, extracting a calculation to a method does not mean that you should call it multiple times within the same method!

You are probably doing `double basePrice = _quantity * _itemPrice;` on more than one place in your code, the idea is that each of those places should be `double basePrice = calcBasePrice();` which makes your code above:

```
double basePrice = calcBasePrice();
if (basePrice > 1000)
    return basePrice * 0.95;
else
    return basePrice * 0.98;

double calcBasePrice() {
    return _quantity * _itemPrice;
}
```

Other suggestions:

- To perform calculations on money, you want **exact** precision. `double` does not have exact percision. You should use `BigDecimal` instead.
- `basePrice()` is not a good method name, I changed  that in my code above to `calcBasePrice()`
- Ident your code properly, as I've done above.

Also, this code:

```
if (basePrice > 1000)
    return basePrice * 0.95;
else
    return basePrice * 0.98;
```

Can use the ternary operator:

```
return basePrice > 1000 ? basePrice * 0.95 : basePrice * 0.98;
```

Or to make it clearer, you can use a `factor` variable.

```
double factor = (basePrice > 1000 ? 0.95 : 0.98);
return basePrice * factor;
```